# Collect performance metrics using Google Cloud Ops Agent and send to Google Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, open-telemetry, google-cloud-ops-agent

I'm looking for a general way to collect performance metrics on several Linux VM instances (Azure, GCP, other) and monitor the metrics in GCP.

On an Ubuntu VM in Azure, I have installed Google Cloud Ops Agent, which uses `fluentd` (to collect logs) and `OpenTelemetry` (to collect performance metrics) behind the scenes.

I added overrides for the two services to set environment variables so that they pick up the service account JSON credentials file, as follows:

- `google-cloud-ops-agent-fluent-bit.service`  `GOOGLE_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS`
- `google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service`  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71150304/run-ops-agent-on-linux-in-azure) for more details on authentication.

I could see log messages appearing in Google Cloud Logging, which must have been scraped and sent by `google-cloud-ops-agent-fluent-bit.service`. However, I couldn't find any performance metrics from `google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector`. *Where should I expect to find these in GCP?* I'm convinced that there is some additional configuration I need to get this working, but the documentation seems to be about getting Ops Agent running on GCP Compute Engine instances.

Update 1:

I can see that the service is running (`sudo systemctl status google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service`), but I now notice errors that I hadn't noticed before which might suggest why metrics are not making it to Google Cloud,

```
exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:215        Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "name": "googlecloud", "error": "rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could no
t be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:1  errors:{sta
tus:{code:9}  point_count:1}", "interval": "5.52330144s"}
```

I don't know where to find the logs for the service other than the excerpt printed by `systemctl status`.

The commandline for the service is `/opt/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/opentelemetry-collector/otelopscol --config=/run/google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector/otel.yaml`. I took a look in the config file and see a few mentions of `googlecloud` as an exporter, e.g.

```
exporters:
  googlecloud:
    metric:
      prefix: ""
    user_agent: Google-Cloud-Ops-Agent-Metrics/2.11.0 (BuildDistro=focal;Platform=linux;ShortName=ubuntu;ShortVersion=20.04)
```

Update 2: Output of service status

```
● google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service - Google Cloud Ops Agent - Metrics Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-03-15 06:36:44 UTC; 1 day 17h ago
    Process: 1053790 ExecStartPre=/opt/google-cloud-ops-agent/libexec/google_cloud_ops_agent_engine -service=otel -in /etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml -logs ${LOGS_DIRECTORY} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1053796 (otelopscol)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 19198)
     Memory: 381.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service
             └─1053796 /opt/google-cloud-ops-agent/subagents/opentelemetry-collector/otelopscol --config=/run/google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector/otel.yaml

Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*metricsSenderWithObservability).send
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]:         /root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.44.0/exporter/exporterhelper/metrics.go:134
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.(*queuedRetrySender).start.func1
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]:         /root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.44.0/exporter/exporterhelper/queued_retry_inmemory.go:105
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.consumerFunc.consume
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]:         /root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.44.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:99
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper/internal.(*boundedMemoryQueue).StartConsumers.func2
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]:         /root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector@v0.44.0/exporter/exporterhelper/internal/bounded_memory_queue.go:78
Mar 16 23:47:37 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: 2022-03-16T23:47:37.980Z        info        exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:215        Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "name": "googlecloud", "error": "[rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0-199]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:200  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:200}; rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0-199]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:200  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:200}; rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0-199]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:200  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:200}; rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0-111]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:112  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:112}]", "interval": "10.435795045s"}
Mar 16 23:47:49 HOSTNAME otelopscol[1053796]: 2022-03-16T23:47:49.299Z        info        exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:215        Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "name": "googlecloud", "error": "rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points.: timeSeries[0-4]\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:5  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:5}", "interval": "44.913550864s"}
```

Comment: Is the `google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector` service running ?

Comment: The `Is the google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector` service is running, but now that I look more closely I see that there are errors like
`{
  "kind": "exporter",
  "name": "googlecloud",
  "error": "[rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: No matching retention policy was found for one or more points ... errors:{status:{ code:9}  point_count:148}]",
  "interval": "17.285707869s"
}`

Comment: Can you provife full output of `sudo systemctl status google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service` ?

Comment: I've added the service status output.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I have not pursued this any further, so unfortunately I don't have a solution. I would love to find one though...